# Windows scripting: Monitor file on shared server and alert upon detected change

Tags: windows, excel, scripting, vbscript, automation

I am looking to create a simple script that will monitor a file on a shared server location containing a date.  When this date changes, I need to display an alert to the user.

Is this possible using built-in Windows tools?  If so, what tools should I be using, and what are some resources that could get me started with this?

Comment: What kind of file are you monitoring?

Comment: Some vbscript methods for monitoring files here: http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/scripts/storage/filesystems/#MFM.htm

Comment: It's just going to be a text file with a date in it, such as `6/5`.  When the file changes, the end goal is to display an alert with items matching the new date.

Comment: Where do the items matching the new date come from?

Comment: Was planning to determine that after getting the file monitoring/alert piece working first.  The end goal is to create a reminder-type system using scripting only -- avoiding custom software if possible.

Comment: In that case the "monitor file modification" sample script from the link I posted should get you started. Save it in a file with a ".vbs" extension and double-click to launch it (after editing the monitored file path of course). It will run in the background, so to kill it you'll need to go into Task Manager and end the "wscript.exe" process.

Comment: Thanks, Tim.  If you post that as an answer, I'll mark it as the correct answer to get you the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "monitor file modification" sample script from here should get you started:

http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/scripts/storage/filesystems/#MFM.htm

Save it in a file with a ".vbs" extension and double-click to launch it (after editing the monitored file path of course). It will run in the background, so to kill it you'll need to go into Task Manager and end the "wscript.exe" process.